# how to check the version of a program from inside autoconf script configure.ac

Tags: r, autoconf

I spent half day trying to figure out whether my question is even feasible to ask or not. There is a MACRO for checking the availability of a program. For example R:

```
AC_PATH_PROG([R], [R], [nor])
```

Is there are standard way of checking the version of R found?  For example, I am trying to base my project with R 3.6.x.  This question could apply to any program of your liking.  I could find out with a shell script:

```
R --version | grep "R version" | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

The above snipit will return the version of R.  Assume I can get this far somehow inside configure.ac, how do I make sure rversion > 3.5.  Is ax_compare_version the way to go?  The following is my test segment.  Getting a little bit wrong. My general question: is my way of doing this acceptable practice?

```
AC_PATH_PROG([R], [R], [nor])
if test "$R" = nor; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([No R installed in this system])
fi
RVERSION=`$R --version | grep "R version" | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
AX_COMPARE_VERSION([$RVERSION], [ge], [3.6.0], AC_MSG_NOTICE([R $RVERSION good]), AC_MSG_ERROR([R $RVERSION too low]))

 checking for R... /usr/local/bin/R
 configure: R 3.6.3 good
```

Note: to use the [AX_COMPARE_VERSION](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compare_version.html#ax_compare_version) you have to copy the m4 file to your project m4 directory or some system location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. The general idea is to turn it into expressions a shell script can evaluate / something you can run from `configure. Below are three different approaches.

The first is some basic tests for `g++` we had in the [RQuantLib configure.ac](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/configure.ac) package for many years (yes, that *many* years that we tested for `g++-3.*` ...). The main gist here is a *wild card comparison*.

```
AC_PROG_CXX
if test "${GXX}" = yes; then
    gxx_version=`${CXX} -v 2>&1 | grep "^.*g.. version" | \\
               sed -e 's/^.*g.. version *//'`
    case ${gxx_version} in
        1.*|2.*)
         AC_MSG_WARN([Only g++ version 3.0 or greater can be used with RQuantib.])
         AC_MSG_ERROR([Please use a different compiler.])
        ;;
    4.6.*|4.7.*|4.8.*|4.9.*|5.*|6.*|7.*|8.*|9.*|10.*)
         gxx_newer_than_45="-fpermissive"
    ;;
    esac
fi
```

Here is another version from [RProtoBuf](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rprotobuf/blob/master/configure.ac) where we compile something to have the version bubble up as a true/false expression:

```
## also check for minimum version
AC_MSG_CHECKING([if ProtoBuf version >= 2.2.0])
AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
int main() {
   if (GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION >= 2001000) {
        exit (0);
   } else {
        exit(1);
   }
}
]])],
[pb_version_ok=yes],
[pb_version_ok=no],
[pb_version_ok=yes])
if test x"${pb_version_ok}" == x"no"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Need ProtoBuf version >= 2.2.0])
else
    AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
fi
```

And I think I did something more recently where I made it an `package_version` object in R so that one can compare---here it is from [RcppRedis](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppredis/blob/master/configure.ac) -- this again comes back to configure as a true/false.

```
## look for (optional !!) MsgPack headers
## RcppMsgPack on CRAN fits the bill -- but is a soft dependency
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for RcppMsgPack])
## Check if R has RcppMsgPack
$("${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript" --vanilla -e 'hasPkg <- "RcppMsgPack" %in% rownames(installed.packages()); q(save="no", status=if (hasPkg) packageVersion("RcppMsgPack") >= "0.2.0" else FALSE)')
if test x"$?" == x"1"; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
    msgpackincdir=$("${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript" --vanilla -e 'cat(system.file("include", package="RcppMsgPack"))')
    msgpack_cxxflags="-I${msgpackincdir} -DHAVE_MSGPACK"
    AC_MSG_NOTICE([Found RcppMsgPack, using '${msgpack_cxxflags}'])
else
    AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
    AC_MSG_NOTICE([Install (optional) RcppMsgPack (>= 0.2.0) from CRAN via 'install.packages("RcppMsgPack")'])
fi
```

I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you. While not without warts, `autoconf` is pretty powerful -- and it is possible to find snippets or even `m4` sub-components. It has served me well for several R packages.  You may find more examples among other CRAN packages which you can search below https://github.com/cran thanks to Gabor's mirroring.